# Scheduling a windows start on C

Tags: c, windows

I'm wondering if it's possible to turn on a computer by itself after shutting it down but without me having to press the button. Let's say that I shut down my computer and I want that it turns on by itself after 10 minutes or 1 hour, or 1 day after. Or maybe I want to restart my computer, but I don't want it to turn on inmediately after going of, I want to set a time in between.

So far I just have a very simple code that can shut it down or restart it, and I can set a time before the restart happens.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think so, how is the program executed if you don't have power??, if it is possible is only at BIOS level, or using some external device which runs your program to power on the computer

Comment: If your computer is turned off, how would the code run to turn it back on?

Comment: there might be an option to do this in your BIOS.  But I don't think there is an OS hook to do that.

Comment: Depends what you mean.  Windows can be asked to wake the computer from sleep or hibernation at a particular time.  Being in hibernation is very nearly the same thing as being off from a hardware point of view, although not from an application's point of view.

Answer (score 1):

The computer itself can't "wakeup" without external help, but there are some ways to make it start without physically pressing the power button.

If the computer was powered down by the UPS due to power outage (wich itself shut down the battery-supplied power afterwards) it is possible (in some machines) to program the BIOS so the machine will be turned on when the power is restored.

If it was powered down by any other means, it is also possible (depending on hardware support) to have wake-up-on-lan enabled. There are many tutorials on how to do it, like [this one](http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan).

Comment: It is also usually possible to program the BIOS to power up the machine at a given time of day.  (For some definition of "usually".)